# Validate django form with a list of values from multiple CheckboxSelectMultiple

Tags: python, django

Using Django2.0, I have set up a form which displays all of my model objects in a list with check boxes. When this is submitted, in my request dict it stores them as a list of IDs. How do i validate these within the form? The clean() method does not get called.

forms:

```
class SampleRunSearchForm(forms.ModelForm):

    sample_run_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            label='Sample Run',
            queryset=SampleRun.objects.all(),
            widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
         )

    class Meta:
        model = SampleRun
        fields = ('sample_run_id',)


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SampleRunSearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('sample_run_id', css_class='sample-run-display',),
            HTML('<br>'),
            Submit('submit', 'Report samples', css_class='upload-btn')
            )

        self.helper.form_method = 'GET'

    def clean_sample_run_id(self): 
        sr_id = self.cleaned_data.getlist('sample_run_id')
        for sr in sr_id:
            ... do something to validate...
            else:
                raise(forms.ValidationError('Error'))
        return(sr_id)
```

views:

```
class SearchSampleRun(View):

    samplerunform = SampleRunSearchForm
    template_name = 'results/samplerun_search_form.html'


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        samplerunform = self.samplerunform()
        if request.GET:
            samplerunform = self.samplerunform(request.GET)
            samplerunform.is_valid()


        context = {'samplerunform': samplerunform}
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

It returns an error to my page that is it not a valid choice.

the clean() method will also execute, but clean_sample_run_id() doesn't work - do i need to iterate through each ID and pass it through the form seperately for validation?!

Comment: If the `sample_run_id` form field is invalid, then Django will not call your `sample_run_id` method. There seems to be a mismatch between the `ModelChoiceField` form field (used to select one item) and `CheckboxSelectMultiple` widget (used to select multiple items).

Comment: I have figured this out - by using forms.MultipleChoiceField, with the widget= forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, it allows me to take a list, and not just a value! thanks!